# where is the java build configuration language in Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1

Tags: java, android

I have been away from android studio for a bit and there used to be a Java build configuration language option.  Not all that I see is 2 Kotlin options and one Groovy option.  I have an Udemy course I want to play with, and it is a Java based android tutorial.  I tried using Kotlin and I get an error of Expecting member declaration when I use public void startGame(View view){}  I also imported android.view.View and it is gray. Which says unused import.  What am I missing?

I have googled for answers to this and have not found an option.  I have reached out to the Udemy author too and no reply.

Comment: The Gradle build configuration has traditionally been Groovy and Kotlin is the "new" joiner. There was never a Java option, so either you are misremembering or you used a different tool. It seems like you're confusing the language for your application code with the language you use to configure your build. Please show us what your full code looks like and where you placed it relative to your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

> I have been away from android studio for a bit and there used to be a Java build configuration language option.

Currently for configuring builds gradle tool is used and scripting language is groovy or kotlin. Java was never an option here. For more details look in here:

https://developer.android.com/build

> I tried using kotlin and I get an error of Expecting member declaration when I use public void startGame(View view){} I also imported android.view.View and it is gray. which says unused import. What am I missing?

It looks like you are trying to use java syntax in a kotlin file (*.kt). In kotlin you dont write `public void` for declaring functions, you should use `fun` keyword. A function should look like:

```
fun startGame(vide: View) {
}
```

for learning kotlin I suggest:

https://developer.android.com/kotlin/learn

Comment: marcinj thanks for the Kotlin function info.... a few years back java was the default language and you could check a box to add Kotlin support.  So that is why I was confused.  How do I create a java app not a Kotlin app with android studio?

Comment: @Dean-O You can choose File->New->New Project, choose for example "Empty Views Activity", then choose Language as Java, and your preferred Build configuration language, I think Groovy DSL is more common, by that I mean you will find more examples in this language on internet.

Comment: Bingo thanks for the help